# Why does my Vim always save a file, no matter what?

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

Whenever I quit a file, even using `:q!`, Vim will save it.  What could possibly be causing this?

**In init:**
ack.vim
    keybindings.vim
    nerdcommenter.vim
    nerdtree.vim
    options.vim
    supertab.vim
    syntastic.vim
    tabline.vim
    vcomments.vim
    vim-fugitive.vim
    vim-powerline.vim

**in plugin:**
EasyMotion.vim
mru.vim

Comment: many possibilities: mapping/plugin(auto-save)/autocmd .... it is hard to say what is the cause to your problem. because we don't know enough information.

Comment: @Kent what information could I provide that would help?

Comment: can you reproduce the problem if you start vim with `vim -u NONE`?

Comment: also you tagged the question with `vim-plugin` but you didn't tell which plugin have you installed.....

Comment: @Kent I added my plugins to the description

Comment: do a binary search on your plugins, meaning remove half of them, if the problem persists try the other half, and apply recursively. also, i have almost the same plugins as you: except tabline, keybingins and vcomment and options. I guess it must be one of those.

Answer (score 5):

Often, a *binary search* where you disable half of your plugins, then only one half of that (when the problem is still there), or the other half (when the problem vanished) lets you get to the problematic script quickly. The same can be done with the configuration in your `~/.vimrc` (by commenting out blocks).

Also, you can capture a full log of a Vim session with `vim -V20vimlog`. After quitting Vim, examine the `vimlog` log file for appropriate commands. In your case, that would be `:write` commands.

Comment: Is there any way to start logging from Vim?

Comment: Yes, the equivalent would be `:set verbosefile=vimlog verbose=20`.